# Mocking database using Entity Framework and Dapper

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, unit-testing, dapper

I am developing a system in c# where, for specific reasons, we are using Entity Framework and Dapper: in some methods, we use Dapper and in other ones, we use Entity Framework.

We need to develop now some unit tests. I've been reading some approaches to mock a database to unit tests. However, most approaches seem specific to EF or Dapper.

Can you suggest a good approach where I can mock a database, simultaneously, to run unit tests that use EF AND Dapper?

For example: in a specific test, I will get a data using Dapper, then use this data to get another data using EF.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is trivial... unless you expect the data pushed in via one test double to be available via the other (i.e. if you store via EF and expect to retrieve via Dapper). Do you need the easy version or the hard version (with state across both)?

Comment: Yeah, I expect the data pushed in via one test double to be available via the other. In some tests, I would get the data by Dapper and use it to get another data in EF in the same test.

Comment: What you need (IMO) is integration tests to test the data access itself. Don't try to mock all that stuff. Sooner or later you'll run into insurmountable  implementation differences between mocks and the real stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this, could be more though.

One doesn't involve databases at all. If you are talking unit testing then focus on smaller bits of work. What I mean by that is that you mock the calls which return data, make them return whatever data you need for your specific test scenario and go from there. No database involved, no need to even think about a database.

In order to do this, your actual datalayers need to be built on top of interfaces or abstract classes and those you can mock to return whatever you want.

If you want to take this further and check that stuff goes correctly in a real database then you are talking about integration tests and you can deal with that by directly calling your various layers and then checking outputs, everything going against real data.

If you go with the first approach then stuff becomes easier because it doesn't matter that one bit uses EF and another Dapper, what matters is only the data you mock and whatever transformations you run against the results.

Answer (score 0):

One option that requires a test database is using dbsafe.
https://github.com/dbsafe/dbsafe
It has a NuGet package as well.

"Tests can be reused if the implementation or the technology used by the DAL changes."

dbsafe provides methods for populating a database, executing SQL commands, and comparing expected data against actual data.

It uses one or more xml input files with SQL scripts and datasets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dbTest>
  <scripts>
    <script name="delete-products">
      DELETE [dbo].[Product];
    </script>

    <script name="delete-categories">
      DELETE [dbo].[Category];
    </script>
  </scripts>

  <datasets>
    <dataset name="categories" setIdentityInsert="true" table="Category">
      <data>
        <row Id="1" Name="category-1" />
        <row Id="2" Name="category-2" />
        <row Id="3" Name="category-3" />
      </data>
    </dataset>

    <dataset name="suppliers" setIdentityInsert="true" table="Supplier">
      <data>
        <row Id="1" Name="supplier-1" ContactName="contact-name-1" ContactPhone="100-200-0001" ContactEmail="email-1@test.com" />
        <row Id="2" Name="supplier-2" ContactName="contact-name-2" ContactPhone="100-200-0002" ContactEmail="email-2@test.com" />
        <row Id="3" Name="supplier-3" ContactName="contact-name-3" ContactPhone="100-200-0003" ContactEmail="email-3@test.com" />
      </data>
    </dataset>  
  </datasets>
</dbTest>
```

The  elements are SQL commands that can be executed any time during the test. E.g. cleaning tables, selecting actual data.

The  elements contain data that can be used to populate a table or as the expected data.

dbsafe supports writing unit tests using the AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert) pattern.

Arrange initializes objects and sets the value of the data that is passed to the method under test.

Method ExecuteScripts can be used to execute scripts to delete old records. Method LoadTables can be used to populate tables.

Act invokes the method under test with the arranged parameters.

Assert verifies that the action of the method under test behaves as expected.

Method AssertDatasetVsScript can be used to compare expected data vs. actual data in the database.